# Error in getFilingsHTML and searchFilings in edgar package of R

Tags: r, edgar

When I run the following two codes from `edgar` package in R, I got the following errors as seen in Output.

**CODE**

The code is here -

```
word.list = c('derivative','hedging','currency forwards','currency futures')
output2 <- searchFilings(cik.no = c('1000180', '38079'),
                        form.type = c("10-K", "10-K405","10KSB", "10KSB40"),
                        filing.year = c(2005, 2006), word.list, useragent)
```

**OUTPUT**

The output is here -

```
Downloading fillings. Please wait... 
  |===========================================================================================| 100%
Searching filings for the input words...
  |=======================                                                                    |  25%Error in if (occur != -1) { : the condition has length > 1
```

**CODE**

```
output <- getFilingsHTML(cik.no = c(1000180, 38079), c('10-K','10-Q'),
                         2006, quarter = c(1, 2, 3), useragent)
```

The output of the above code

**OUTPUT**

```
Downloading fillings. Please wait... 
  |==========================================================================================| 100%
Scrapping full EDGAR and converting to HTML...
  |                                                                                          |   0%Error in if (!grepl(pattern = "<xml>|<type>xml|<html>", filing.text, ignore.case = T)) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```